# From Text-to-Speech to mp3 on a Mac

Tags: macos, mac, audio, recording

I wonder if there is an easy way to record the audio while a text is been read by my Mac using the built-in text-to-speech menu item of the text editor (TextEdit) of Mac OS X ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try to execute the following in a terminal:

```
say -o ~/Desktop/say.aiff  "Hello. I'm a Mac"
```

That will save the spoken text "Hello. I'm a Mac" to ~/Desktop/say.aiff. See the manpage of say (execute `man say` in a terminal) for more information and other file formats. You can also easily convert the .aiff-File to an mp3 with iTunes or a console based encoder like lame.

Comment: You can also substitute the `"Hello. I'm a Mac"` for any text file

Comment: ... and I personally recommend adding `-v Zarvox` as the first option in the above command ;-)

Comment: substituting the String with a textfile won't work (or did you mean to substitute with the contents of said file?). But you can do this: `cat textfile.txt | say -o ~/Desktop/say.aiff` . It will make "say" speak the contents of textfil.txt and output it to say.aif.

Comment: my mistake. You can use `say -f /path/to/file/file.txt`

Comment: You can write `say -v ?` to display a list of all available voices on your system.

Answer (score 2):

Honestly, I know it's not explicitly what you're asking for, but this is much faster and better. Select everything in the doc, `right click > services > add to itunes as a spoken track`. Then, Your file gets processed directly instead as an audio file. No terminal needed. Youtube video explanation: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dGEs77682s0

If you really want your computer to be reading to you while you're recording, you can do a quicktime audio recording using [soundflower](https://rogueamoeba.com/freebies/soundflower/). SoundFlower is an app that sends your computers internal sounds to the recording.